# Google Looker Studio: Finding an aggregate across teams to compare variance above/below department performance

Tags: looker-studio

I'm looking to add a column to a table in Looker Studio that would be an "overall" average for a department and compare to the individual team performance. Essentially, I want to be able to see how far above/below the department average each team is. I am the teams in column 1 with the closing ratio in column 2, looking to add "Department ratio" in column 3. Is this doable?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujTEu.png)

Expecting to see a 3rd column that would show the overall average. This value would be the same on each row.